# A cut made through vlcj does not match requested interval

Tags: java, vlcj

please take a look at this code sample. It is supposed to cut 10 seconds from a sample video (30 to 40).

```
public Example() {
    factory = new MediaPlayerFactory();
    mediaPlayer = factory.newHeadlessMediaPlayer();
}

public void start(Semaphore semaphore) {

    String fileName =  "/home/damian/Videos/SampleVideo_1080x720_30mb.mp4";
    Media media = new SimpleMedia(fileName);
    mediaPlayer.playMedia(fileName, ":start-time=30", ":stop-time=40", ":sout=#transcode{vcodec=h264,vb=4096,scale=1,acodec=mpga,ab=128,channels=2,samplerate=44100}:duplicate{dst=file{dst=" + "/home/damian/vout/v.mp4" + "}}");
    mediaPlayer.addMediaPlayerEventListener(new MediaPlayerEventAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void finished(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
            mediaPlayer.stop();
            mediaPlayer.release();
            semaphore.release();
        }
    });
```

The problem with the result it that it always contains like 0.5 second of the initial sample at the very beggining. So for a blink of an eye I can see the beggining of original video and then the 10 requested seconds. Does anyone know how to get rid of this problem?

Comment: vlcj does nothing here except pass those parameters to VLC, so there's likely nothing  you can do about it unfortunately.

Comment: OK, nevermind. I used moviepy which works and has a very good API.